# Plotly python scatterplot matrix column names in hovertemplate

Tags: python, plotly

In python I create a plotly graph objects scatter plot matrix as followed:

```
eval_columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'etc']
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Splom(
            dimensions=[dict(label=col, values=df[col]) for col in eval_columns],
            showupperhalf=False,
            text=df['col3'],
            marker=dict(color=df['col3'],
                        showscale=False, 
                        line_color='white', line_width=0.5),
            ))
```

The hoverlabel in the resulting scatter plot matrix shows by default (x,y) values.
I would like to add the name of the respective column in front of x and y.
How can I manage this?

The documentation on hovertemplates says: every attribute that can be specified per-point can be accessed in the hovertemplate definition. Column names however are not per_point attributes.

Any ideas on how to do that? I know that px.scatter_matrix automatically assigns the column names to the hover labels, however I need to use go.Splom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover template is automatically set in `px.scatter_matrix()`, so if you get its data structure, you will find a description of the hover template, which you can apply to `go.Splom()`. The sample in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/splom/#splom-of-the-iris-data-set) supports this.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/iris-data.csv')

# The Iris dataset contains four data variables, sepal length, sepal width, petal length,
# petal width, for 150 iris flowers. The flowers are labeled as `Iris-setosa`,
# `Iris-versicolor`, `Iris-virginica`.

# Define indices corresponding to flower categories, using pandas label encoding
index_vals = df['class'].astype('category').cat.codes

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Splom(
                dimensions=[dict(label='sepal length',
                                 values=df['sepal length']),
                            dict(label='sepal width',
                                 values=df['sepal width']),
                            dict(label='petal length',
                                 values=df['petal length']),
                            dict(label='petal width',
                                 values=df['petal width'])],
                text=df['class'],
    hovertemplate='%{xaxis.title.text}=%{x}<br>%{yaxis.title.text}=%{y}',
                marker=dict(color=index_vals,
                            showscale=False, # colors encode categorical variables
                            line_color='white', line_width=0.5)
                ))


fig.update_layout(
    title='Iris Data set',
    dragmode='select',
    width=600,
    height=600,
    hovermode='closest',
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The data structure will be output in `fig.data`, so if you check it, you will be able to understand it better in the future plotly. If you find my answer helpful, please click on the check mark to accept the answer.